# Docker maximum offline containers

Tags: docker

I've read about the [limitations on Docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#specifying-custom-cgroups), and also on [the maximum number of container running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801470/3243814), but I'd like to do the following:

- Start a container on-the-fly (milliseconds).

In order to do so, I've noticed that I have to `create` it beforehand; this will save me about 2 seconds each time. This made me wonder:

- Is there any limitation to the number of created containers? Do they use *any* resources?

  - obviously it uses disk space to store it
  - does it also preload it in RAM, or not?

    - related: is the "active" state of the process saved on stopping, or is it the process stopped, and started on `start`? (if the latter is the case, then why would anyone bother to re-create containers? )
  - does it have a reserved IP address? And if so, is there a maximum number of private IP addresses Docker will use?
  - ... anything else that might prevent me from having 50,000 containers?

Comment: 2 seconds? Are you using a boot2docker-like type of environment, with a Linux VM?

Comment: Using the Remote API to issue the create command (image is about 14MB), running locally (Linux 64bit; 8 cores @ 3.4GHz, but only a HDD - no SSD).

Comment: I meant are you on Linux directly, or using docker through a Linux VM?

Comment: Ok, I did experience long docker run time (but I do quite a lot in my run scripts though, as in https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/1a3a147bb59a209f1cedd0c37c4a2cddef3d6ea5/gitolite/run#L33)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know (I appreciate it). I apologize for asking, but, how does this help?

Comment: I was just curious to see if your execution environment might explain the high startup time. As for your questions, I am still reading https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/

Comment: Well, the fact that you were experiencing faster builds than I, was kind of interesting (and helped). Using RAMFS instead of a regular HDD, boosted the build time from 2400ms to 400ms.

Answer (score 1):

If a container is only created, there is no running process (and nothing is [pre-]cached either).  I've also verified that if the container isn't running yet, the `NetworkSettings` section of `docker inspect` is blank, so no IP addresses should be allocated in this case.  The metadata stored on disk to track the "container object" should be the only impact (and whatever memory the Docker daemon uses at runtime while keeping track of said metadata, which likely includes a copy of the metadata itself).

I've run `for i in {0..999}; do docker create --name hello-$i hello-world; done` on my local machine to test this, and it completed successfully (although took what seems like an embarrassingly long time to complete, given that it's looking up and writing out the exact same metadata repeatedly).